# how to find a row in dataset, which has maximum number of cells using pandas library?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, max, argmax

for example:

```
index1 dog 32 height 
index2 cat 20 height weight
```

In this example, the second row has 5 columns so how to find the row which maximum columns(cells)?

Comment: `df.notnull().sum(1).idxmax()`?

Answer (score 0):

If `df` data frame has multiple rows having the same maximum value of not empty columns then use:

```
df[df.notnull().sum(1)==df.notnull().sum(1).max()]
```

This selects rows which have number of not empty columns equal to maximum of it across entire data set.